# What standard Siebel eScript actually based on?

Tags: javascript, oracle, siebel, escript, ecmascript-4

According to [Siebel 8.0 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/eScript/eScript_JSLOverview2.html) eScript is compliant with ECMAScript Edition 4 standard. But as far as I have learned there is no such standard published. Edition 4 was in draft state for a long time, but was never released. [ECMA's website](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262-arch.htm) states Edition 4 as "NOT EXISTING". I've found [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329602/why-was-ecmascript-4th-edition-completely-scrapped) where some light shed to details. Furthermore in [Siebel 8.1/8.2 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/eScript/Overview_eScript2.html) Oracle totally removed references to ECMA standards and now we have evasive "Siebel eScript is a programming language that is syntactically and semantically compatible with JavaScript". So my question is: what specific standard Siebel eScript actually based on? What should anyone expect regarding support of syntax/features? Should it be trial and error method or there is some point to start with?

Disclaimer: Yes, I know there is "Siebel eScript Language Reference" in Bookshelf. I just want to know if there are any additional ECMAScript or Javascript specs/references that are applicable to
eScript too.

Comment: What makes you think it wasn't based on the draft standard?

Comment: I think it is possible. There are several revisions on http://www.ecmascript.org/es4/spec/. So if anyone knows specific draft revision I would accept it as an answer.