# ECMA Script 4 - what's the story behind?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-4

I am researching the history of Java Script and spent hours trying to understand what has happened to ECMA Script 4 standard. What were the differences between ES3 and ES4? So, what's the story behind it's being abandoned?

Thank you

UPD: The answer is here: [Why was ECMAScript 4th edition completely scrapped?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329602/why-was-ecmascript-4th-edition-completely-scrapped)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2329602/why-was-ecmascript-4th-edition-completely-scrapped Is this not what you're looking for?

Comment: @Daedalus Looks like it. Thank you. Closing this one.

Comment: microsoft killed it because silverlight...